# Error on Heap in my Sorting Algorithms Program

Tags: c++, qt-creator

In this program I am loading in different data sets to test the Merge, Bubble and Insertion sorting algorithms. I have been working on bits and pieces and this is an early iteration. For some reason my code randomly crashes, more so these last 10 runs. After running the debugger it takes me to random spot on the heap, but doesn't give any more information on the problem with the program, I have pinpointed it to my sort.cpp file but still cant get it. I don't believe its a memory leak, and I am not using pointers so everything should exist. If you could help me troubleshoot the program I would appreciate it.

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "merge.h"
#include "bubble.h"
#include "insertion.h"
#include "createfile.h"
#include "sort.h"
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "You can do it Xavier, I believe in you" << endl;
        //========================================
        //Sort Random Sets
        //========================================
        SortRandom();
        //========================================
        //Sort Backward Sets
        //========================================
       // SortBackwards();
        //========================================
        //Sort sets with 20% Unique
        //========================================
    //    Sort20Percent();
        //========================================
        //Sort sets with 30% randomized
        //========================================
     //   Sort30Percent();

    }
```

sort.cpp

```
#include "sort.h"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "bubble.h"
#include "insertion.h"
#include "merge.h"
using namespace std;

    void SortRandom()
    {
        sort random;
        //Sorts 10 set
        random.load("Random(10).txt");
        random.execute();
        random.stats();
        random.save("Random(10)Stats.txt");
        cout << "====================" << endl;
        //Sorts 1000 set
        random.load("Random(1000).txt");
        random.execute();
        random.stats();
        random.save("Random(1000)Stats.txt");
        cout << "====================" << endl;
        //Sorts 10,000 set
        random.load("Random(10000).txt");
        random.execute();
        random.stats();
        random.save("Random(10000)Stats.txt");
        cout << "====================" << endl;
        //Sorts 100,000 set
        random.load("Random(100000).txt");
        random.execute();
        random.stats();
        random.save("Random(100000)Stats.txt");

    }
```

sort.h

```
#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H
#include "algorithm.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
class sort : public algorithm
{
    private:
        vector<int> dataset;
        string file;
        string time1;
        string time2;
        string time3;
public:
    //loads file into program
    void load(string filename)
    {
        ifstream inFile;
        ofstream writefile;
        inFile.open(filename);
        file = filename;
        int entry;
        string str;
            while(std::getline(inFile, str))
            {
                inFile >> entry;
                dataset.push_back(entry);
            }

    }

    //Print the unsorted vector
    void print()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<dataset.size();i++)
        {
            cout << dataset[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    //Sort set and time it
    void execute()
    {
        vector<int> temp1 = dataset;
        vector<int> temp2 = dataset;
        vector<int> temp3 = dataset;
        //Time for bubblesort
        using timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
                timer::time_point start_time = timer::now();
        bubblesort(temp1);
        timer::time_point end_time = timer::now();
            cout << "Total Time for BubbleSort: " << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << "ms" << endl;

        //Time for MergeSort
        using timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
                timer::time_point start_time2 = timer::now();
        MergeSort(temp2,0,temp2.size());
        timer::time_point end_time2 = timer::now();
            cout << "Total Time for MergeSort " << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time2 - start_time2).count() << "ms" << endl;

        //Time for Insertion Sort
        using timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
                timer::time_point start_time3 = timer::now();
        insertionsort(temp3,temp3.size());
        timer::time_point end_time3 = timer::now();
            cout << "Total Time for Insertion Sort " << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time3 - start_time3).count() << "ms" << endl;

        //Save time variables
        ostringstream x,y,z;
        x << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
        time1 = x.str();
        y << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time2 - start_time2).count();
        time2 = y.str();
        z << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time3 - start_time3).count();
        time3 = z.str();

        dataset = temp1;
    }

    //print sorted vector to screen
    void display()
    {
        insertionsort(dataset,dataset.size());
        for(int i=0;i<dataset.size();i++)
        {
            cout << dataset[i] << ',';
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "===============================================" << endl;
    }

    //Print the size of the dataset,method and time it took
    void stats()
    {
        cout << "To sort this data set of size " << dataset.size() << " using the bubblesort method took " << time1 << " ms." << endl;
        cout << "To sort this data set of size " << dataset.size() << " using the mergesort method took " << time2 << " ms." << endl;
        cout << "To sort this data set of size " << dataset.size() << " using the insert sort method took " << time3 << " ms." << endl;
    }

    //Save stats to a file
    void save(string filename)
    {
        ofstream writefile;
        writefile.open(filename);
        writefile << "\n";
        writefile << "===========================================================================" << "\n" << endl;
        writefile << "To sort this data set of size " << dataset.size() << " using the bubblesort method took " << time1 << " ms." << endl;
        writefile << "To sort this data set of size " << dataset.size() << " using the mergesort method took " << time2 << " ms." << endl;
        writefile << "To sort this data set of size " << dataset.size() << " using the insert sort method took " << time3 << " ms." << endl;
        writefile << "===========================================================================" << "\n" << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<dataset.size();i++)
        {
            writefile << dataset[i];
            writefile << ',';
            }

            dataset.clear();
        }


};
void SortRandom();
void SortBackwards();
void Sort20Percent();
void Sort30Percent();

#endif // SORT_H
```

Comment: The bug is most likely in code that you have not shown..

Comment: Perhaps you are running out of virtual memory.

Comment: ***my code randomly crashes*** Usually this is a clear indication of Undefined Behavior (assuming your PC is stable).

Comment: You have a naming conflict.  There already exists a `sort` function in `namespace std`.  The `using namespace std;` brings the `std::sort` into the namespace to collide with your `sort` class.  I recommend not `using namespace std;`.  You would be safer by identifying individual symbols, such as `using std::ifstream;`, rather including the entire namespace.

Comment: Turn the warnings level to maximum and resolve them.

Comment: Also, be aware that `random` is also in the `std::` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The function sort::load() can be the problem: the vector dataset is continiously reallocated when push_back() is called. With a big enought data set, your program will get a memory allocation failure.

one way to fix that is using dataset.reserve( MAX_DATASET_SIZE) to initialize its capacity at the begining of your program.